# Javascript - How to display Next Wednesday date on a html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I already check on stackoverflow if there is a solution for my problem, but as I'm not good with Javascript I was not able to adapt any solution I've find.

I just need a small snippet to paste in the HTML page.

I think the problem is quite easy for you PRO!

I run a meeting every Wednesday at 20:30 pm and I need to create a small JS that display the next date of the meeting. For Example:

Today is Wednesday 18th 2018 and on the page must appear that the meeting will be today (this evening at 20:30 ofc).

Here is a screen of the zone of the page where I need to put the JS code (or other language if you suggest me).  www.maurolangiu.com/business-meeting

I also need that the time is in Italian Format with DAY - NUMBER - MONTH - YEAR.

I don't need to put the time in the script as It doesn't change...

[image: Date Problem]

At 20:31 of today, the script would automatically turn the date on the next Wednesday 25th July 2018 and continue just like that.

Right now I have to change manually the time via FTP and it is quite bad.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: I think this little script will make it `var nextWednesday = new Date();
    nextWednesday.setDate(nextWednesday.getDate() + (3 + 7 - nextWednesday.getDay()) % 7);
    alert(nextWednesday)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do the trick no library needed and formatted in the way you wanted it.
Simply sets the date to next Wednesday and if today is Wednesday and its after 20:30 then go to next week already.

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + (3 + 7 - d.getDay()) % 7);

if(d.getDay() == 3 && d.getHours() > 19 && d.getMinutes() > 30){
d.setDate(d.getDate() + (3 + 7 - d.getDay()));
}

var options = {'weekday': 'long', 'month': 'long', 'day': '2-digit', 'year': 'numeric'};
var date = d.toLocaleString('it-IT', options);
console.log(date);
```

EDIT: First of all your going to add a script element in which you'll have to add my code above. Then if I looked at your code there is this part

```
<h4 class="card-title">Mercoledi 18 Luglio 2018</h4>
```

In which you'll have to delete the text 'Mercoledi 18 Luglio 2018' and just leave it empty. Then you add an unique id to it eg. `<h4 class="card-title" id="nextMeeting">.` and lastly replace in my javascript code the last line `console.log(date);` with

```
document.getElementById('nextMeeting').innerHTML = date.toString();
```

I think this should resolve it.

Comment: this condition must be  if(d.getDay() == 3 && d.getHours() >= 20 && d.getMinutes() > 30)

Comment: @mbadeveloper isn't >19 or >= 20  the same? like 20 is bigger then 19 or am I really brainfarting at the moment :p?

Comment: Hey this is very nice! I get it in Italian, but how can I put this in my HTML page? Here: www.maurolangiu.com/business-meeting

Comment: @mrdeadsven Yes its the same :)

Comment: @MauroLangiu I made edits to my answer try them out and see if it works :).

Comment: @mrdeadsven you are amazing! This just solve my problem! Now it looks perfect! Tonight I will test if it automatically goes on next Wednesday ;) Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

```
// day in number where Monday is 1, and so on...
// hour is an hour in 24-hour format
// min is minutes

function getNextDay(day, hour, min){
    let date = new Date();
    let currentDay = date.getDay();
    let currentHours = date.getHours();
    let currentMins = date.getMinutes();
    let newDate = new Date();
    if(day == currentDay && currentHours <= hour){
        if(currentMins< min)
            return date;
    }else if(day == currentDay)
        newDate.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
    else
        newDate.setDate(date.getDate() + (day + 7 - currentDay) % 7);
    return newDate;
}
```

just call this function you will get next day

to change the format of date like this dd/mm/yyyy you can call this function

```
function changeFormat(today){
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){
    dd='0'+dd;
} 
if(mm<10){
    mm='0'+mm;
} 
var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
console.log(today);
//document.getElementById("DATE").value = today;
}
changeFormat(getNextDay(3,20,30));
```

this will work for you.

Comment: Hello is it possible to get it in Italian? If not, could you please help me in displaying just the date in this format 18/07/2018 ?

Answer (score 2):

If the current day is Sunday, Monday or Tuesday - you have to add 3 or 2 or 1 days. Otherwise you have to add 7/6/5/4 days. This means that the offset for Sunday/Monday/Tuesday is `3 - day_of_week` and for the rest is `10 - day_of_week`

```
<script>
function nextWednesday()
{
    var today = new Date();
    var todayN = today.getDay();
    var offset = (todayN < 3 ? 3 : 10) - todayN; // <--- the most important part
    today.setDate(today.getDate() + offset);
    return today;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

hero you go.. paste this in your html page, then set the id of the date div to `datediv`

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var today = new Date();
    var todayN = today.getDay();
    var def = todayN - 3;
    var NextWednesday  = new Date();
    NextWednesday.setDate(today.getDate()+def);
    document.getElementById("datediv").innerHTML = NextWednesday;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[chrono](https://github.com/wanasit/chrono) is a library that allows for parsing dates from natural language expressions. See the example demonstrating your use case:

```js
function eh_onLoad ( eve ) {
    let dtx;
    dtx = chrono.parseDate(
       'This Wednesday, 8pm, or next Wednesday, 8pm' // The string to parse.
     , new Date()                                    // The reference datetime: right now ...
     , { forwardDate: true}                          // ... only computing future dates
    );
    document.querySelector('#asDate').appendChild(document.createTextNode(dtx));
}
```

```css
#asDate { background-color: lightgrey; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SO Date Math in natural language</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chrono-node/chrono.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="eh_onLoad()">
        <p><span>This Wednesday, 8pm, or next Wednesday, 8pm</span>: <span id="asDate"></span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

While the locales do not include Italian, the D-M-Y date format is supported.

The natural language parser has its limits, of course. Elisions for example are not supported; the shortcut `This or next Wednesday, 8 pm` would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a `switch` statement to find out how many days are left until the next Wednesday. Then you can add those days to the current date.

```js
const currentDate = new Date();
let daysLeft = 0;

switch(currentDate.getDay()) {
  case 0:
   daysLeft = 4;
        break;
  case 1:
   daysLeft = 5;
        break
  case 2:
   daysLeft = 6;
        break;
  case 3: // it's wednesday
    // Check for the time (20:30)
    if (currentDate.getHours() > 20 && currentDate.getMinutes() > 30) {
     daysLeft = 6;
    }
    else {
     daysLeft = 0;
    }   
    break;
  case 4:
   daysLeft = 1;
        break;
  case 5:
   daysLeft = 2;
        break;
  case 6:
   daysLeft = 3
        break;
}

currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + daysLeft); 

const day = currentDate.getDate();
const month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
const year = currentDate.getFullYear();

const meetingDate = `${day}/${month}/${year}`;

document.getElementById('meeting-date').innerHTML = meetingDate;
```

```html
<div id="meeting-date"></div>
```

Comment: Hi this is very nice, but how can I insert this snippet in my html page ?

Comment: @MauroLangiu I have edited my answer. Just make sure you include an element with the ID `meeting-date` in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give an identifier for the event tag like:

```
<h4 id="nextEvent" class="card-title">Mercoledi 18 Luglio 2018</h4>
```

Then placefollowing code in the script section

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var today = new Date();
var todayDate = today.getDate();
var day = today.getDay();
var differrence = day - 3;
var nextDate  = new Date();
var options = {'weekday': 'long', 'month': 'long', 'day': '2-digit', 'year': 'numeric'};  

if(day == 3 && today.getHours() > 19 && today.getMinutes() > 30){
  nextDate.setDate(todayDate + (3 + 7 - day));
}
else{
 nextDate.setDate(todayDate + differrence);
}

$("#nextEvent").text(nextDate.toLocaleString('it-IT', options));
});
```